# how to split string copied from excel column? (using jQuery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want the way to split string copied from excel column.
I want to use that copied string in jQuery.

But problem is that when we copy any column from excel then it gives that column data as single string.

I am developing an application in asp.net in which I am  having one requirement that user will copy the numbers from excel column and paste in application (i use multi-line textbox).

is any other way for doing this instead of using textbox?

Comment: Can you show the copied string sample..?

Comment: Hi sudhir,
if you have column in excel say like "Name"
and that column contains names like
"Name"
A
B
C
D

then if you copy this column and access the value using jQuery it will give "ABCD"
Remember this column copy and paste in multiline textbox in asp.net application.
Thanks

Comment: Hello Friends.. my problem resolved.. i use the clipboard data to get the data and separate it here is link.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jebarson/archive/2010/06/29/copy-and-paste-excel-or-clipboard-data-to-gridview-in-asp-net.aspx